# Image aspect ratio wrong after changing src

Tags: jquery

I'm using a script to scale and image to fill the background while preserving the aspect ratio.  And I'm also using thumbails to swap out that background image.  If the new image doesn't match the original image in aspect, distortion occurs.  Its obviously still using the old size data from the original image.  How can I fix this?

EDIT: Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TKGYu/2/) You can see it in action.  This uses links instead of thumbnails (top left corner)

Resizing code (not mine):

```
$(window).load(function() {    

        var theWindow        = $(window),
        bgImg              = $("#bg");

        function resizeImg() {
        var imgwidth = bgImg.width();
        var imgheight = bgImg.height();
        var winwidth = $(window).width();
        var winheight = $(window).height();
        var widthratio = winwidth / imgwidth;
        var heightratio = winheight / imgheight;
        var widthdiff = heightratio * imgwidth;
        var heightdiff = widthratio * imgheight;
        var topPos = -(heightdiff-winheight) /2;
        var leftPos = -(widthdiff-winwidth) /2;
        if(heightdiff>winheight) {
            bgImg.css({
                width: winwidth+'px',
                height: heightdiff+'px',
                left:"0px",
                top:topPos+"px"
            });
        }
        else {
            bgImg.css({
                width: widthdiff+'px',
                height: winheight+'px',
                left:leftPos+"px",
                top:"0px"
            });     
        }
        $(".marker").html(bgImg.width()+" x "+bgImg.height());
    } 

      theWindow.resize(resizeImg).trigger("resize");            
});
```

Trigger code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".thumbs").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#bg").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
        });
    });
```

Comment: Looks like you're only triggering the resize when the window is resized, which wouldn't resize the image of a clicked thumbnail until after the window is resized? Try adding a resize call to the click function as well?

Comment: Even if the window is resized, the incorrect aspect remains.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change two things in your script:

```
     if(bgImg.width()>bgImg.height()){
        bgImg.css({
            width: 'auto',
            height: $(window).height()+'px',
            left:"0px",
            top:topPos+"px"
        });
    }
    else {
        bgImg.css({
            width: $(window).width()+'px',
            height: 'auto',
            left:leftPos+"px",
            top:"0px"
        });     
    }
```

Main idea is setting one dimension strictly (ex: `100px`) and another to `auto` — browser's engine will take care of the image's aspect raion after that. and no distortion will occur.

Second thing you have to change in your script: call `resizeImg()`, in `<img>`'s onload

Answer (score 0):

You can check, did I understand your goal or not: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nhYxT/). 
Pure CSS might help:

```
<style>
#backgroundDiv
{
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    top:0;
    z-index:-1;
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/9bIasTp.jpg");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

}
</style>

<div id="backgroundDiv"></div>
```